# Transforming CSV column names in Azure Synapse during implicit copy

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am making a data pipeline in Azure Synapse. I want to copy a 500 GB CSV file from a Blob container file and convert it into an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 table. Before I copy it into the table, I want to make some changes to the data using a Data Flow block, to change some column names and other transformations.

1. Is it possible to copy the data and make transformations implicitly, without a staging Parquet store ?
2. If yes, how do I make the transformations implicitly ? Ex: Remove dashes ("-") from all column names ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **rule-based mapping** in the `select` transformation to remove the Hyphen symbol from all the column names.

Matching condition: `true()`

Output column name expression: `replace($$, '-','')`

[image]

Select output:

[image]